# PL/SQL expression cannot be used

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When trying to run the below sql I am getting the following error:

Error: PLS-00363: expression 'PNUM' cannot be used as an assignment target
Line: 622

```
Procedure insertRec(pNum In VARCHAR2
                    ,pName in VARCHAR2)
Is
Begin

    IF  pNum ='0' Then
      pNum = '100';
   End;

  Insert into insertNum(Num,Name) values(pNum,pName);    

End;
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to work with strings? The names `Num` and `pNum` suggest you are expecting numbers. One possible issue: `' 0'` and `'0 '` don't equal `'0'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pnum` is an `IN` parameter; why would you set it to some other value? If you insist on doing that, make it an `IN OUT` parameter which makes things complicated as you can't just *call* that procedure, but declare a variable that will be passed to the procedure (as you have to put that `OUT` value *somewhere*).

Also, you don't assign a value with `=`, but `:=` (i.e. `pnum := '100';`).

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table insertnum (num varchar2(10), name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure insertrec (pnum in out varchar2, pname in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    if pnum = '0' then
  4       pnum := '100';
  5    end if;
  6    insert into insertnum (num, name) values (pnum, pname);
  7  end ;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_n varchar2(10) := '0';
  3  begin
  4    insertrec(l_n, 'x');
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> select * from insertnum;

NUM        NAME
---------- --------------------
100        x

SQL>
```

---

However, that should be rewritten with `DECODE` (or `CASE`) as

```
SQL> create or replace procedure insertrec (pnum in varchar2, pname in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    insert into insertnum (num, name) values (decode(pnum, '0', '100', pnum), pname);
  4  end ;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    insertrec('20', 'y');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From insertnum;

NUM        NAME
---------- --------------------
100        x
20         y

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of a IN parameter. Declare a variable instead.

```
PROCEDURE insertRec(pNum IN VARCHAR2, pName IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    num pNum%Type;
BEGIN
    num := pNum;
    IF pNum ='0' THEN
        num := '100';
    END;

    INSERT INTO insertNum(Num,Name) VALUES(num,pName);    
END;
```

Comment: That's not entirely correct. You can assign a new value to a parameter if its type is `IN OUT` or `OUT` - in fact, `OUT` parameters would be pretty useless if you couldn't assign to them.